# PhpStorm - WSL2 - PHPUnit - Configure CLI Interpreter

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I upgraded to WSL2 from Windows 10.

With PhpStorm, in my project that I switched under my WSL, I try to launch PHPUnit. But I have this error :

> Error in bootstrap script:
> Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the
> "\WSL$\UBUNTU\home\toto\symfony\myProject/.env" environment file.

By looking in the parameters at the CLI Interpreter level, I saw that there was still my Windows config:

[image]

So, if the problem is there, I imagine that I have to make sure to take the PHP Executable from my WSL. Except that .. well impossible to find it
I have the file in `usr/bin/php`, or `usr/bin/php7.4`, but neither is accepted. And in `\etc\php\7.4`, I have these 3 folders:

[image]

But the same, there's nothing in it that can be accepted.

Comment: You need to point to the php **executable** file and not a folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a PHP interpreter of the Local type, while you need to use the WSL type. Here's what the UI looks like:

[image: PhpStorm WSL Interperter]

Click the `+` icon, choose `From Docker, Vagrant, VM, WSL, Remote...`, and choose WSL in there.